# Symfony2 Transformer doesn't receive value

Tags: php, regex, forms, symfony

I created a custom form type and a transformer that goes with it.
Data in my database is saved in 1 Text field. "`<EN>English text</EN><FR>Frenc text</FR>`"

So I created a formtype that added separate text for each input and the transformer is suposed to put the right value in between the tags inside the input.

the problem is I echoed the value that should be passed in the transform function but it's empty and I can't figure out why.

here is my multilang type

```
class MultiLangType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'compound' => 'true'
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $langs = array('EN', 'FR', 'DE');
        $transformer = new StringToMultiTransformer($langs);
        $builder->prependClientTransformer($transformer);
        //$builder->addModelTransformer(new StringToMultiTransformer($langs));
        foreach($langs as $l)
        {
            $builder->add($l, 'text', $options);
        }

    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'field';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'multilang';
    }
}
```

and now my transformer

```
class StringToMultiTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $langs;

    public function __construct(array $langs)
    {
        $this->langs = $langs;
    }

    public function transform($value)
    {
        // var_dump($value); exit;
        $result = array();

        foreach ($this->langs as $l) {
            $ret = preg_match("/<$l>(.*?)<\/$l>/", $value);
            $result[$l] = $ret[1];
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function reverseTransform($array)
    {
        if (!is_array($array)) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($array, 'array');
        }

        $result = "";
        $emptyKeys = array();

        foreach ($this->langs as $l) {
            $val = $array[$l];
            $result .= "<$l>$val</$l>";
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your transformer is called multiple times. So, I think you should use early return by checking if the passed $value is null.

Add at the top of your `transform()` method logic,

```
if (!$value) {
    return null;
}
```

You should also do the same within your `reverseTransform()` method to avoid taking into account empty and null values.

Comment: Thank you! You just saved my night rest, now that it's all working. I had no idea it got called multiple times, still not really an idea why.